# Rspec: Comment rendered as created by a user different from logged in user

Tags: rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm new to rspec and capybara and learning by slowly expanding my test scenarios.

I am unable to understand why a comment which i created after logging in (eg. Friend), is instead printed out as created by another test user (eg. Test1)?

(I have checked in browser and comment is shown as created by the current user)

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'navigate' do

  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:friend) { FactoryGirl.create(:friend) }
  let!(:article) {
    Article.create(title:"To test notifications", summary: "Summary of article", description: "Description of article.", status: "published", user_id: user.id)
  }

  describe 'notification created if other use comments on article' , js: true do

    before do
      login_as(friend, :scope => :user)
      visit article_path(article)
        fill_in 'comment[content]', with: "Some comments"
      click_on "Add Comment"
      logout(:friend)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    end

    it "renders notification on dropdown list" do
      expect(page).to have_css("#notificationList", text: friend.name + " posted a Comment on " + article.title)
      expect(page).to have_css("#notification-counter", text: "1")
    end

    it "render notification on notifiction index page" do
      visit notifications_path
      expect(page).to have_css("#notifications-container", text: friend.name + " posted a Comment on " + article.title)
    end

  end

end
```

I have tried below method too but the test fails because I am unable to log in to the app.

2) Replace `login_as(friend, :scope => :user)` with `login_as(friend, :scope => :friend)`

**User factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "test#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Test#{n}" }
    email { generate :email }
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"
  end

  factory :friend, class: "User" do
    name 'Friend'
    email { generate :email }
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a logic error in your controller/view that is causing is (it works in dev mode) this is likely caused by you not waiting for actions to complete in your test.  Easiest way to test that is to put `sleep 2` after `click_on` and `logout`.  If that fixes the issue then the proper solution is to add expectations for things that appear when an action is completed

```
before do
  login_as(friend, :scope => :user)
  visit article_path(article)
  fill_in 'comment[content]', with: "Some comments"
  click_on "Add Comment"
  expect(page).to have_text "Comment Added" # whatever is shown once "Add Comment" succeeds
  logout(:friend)
  expect(page).to have_text "You have logged out" # whatever change indicates logout has completed
  login_as(user, :scope => :user)
end
```

This is because `click_on` is not guaranteed to wait for any actions (it has no way of knowing what those actions may be) triggered by clicking.  In your case that means the "Add Comment" is clicked, immediately following that whatever `logout` does happens, and then you call `login_as`.  `login_as` works by telling the warden/devise middleware to act as if the specified user is logged in for the next request, so if that happens before the request being made from the "Add Comment" click gets processed it's possible for the "Add Comment" request to be processed as if `user` made it rather than `friend`.  By adding sleeps or expectations between you give time for the action to occur as the correct user and ensure it has completed before moving on in the test.

Additionally the devise/warden provided `login_as` doesn't actually visit a page, so if that is the version of `login_as` you're using you probably need a `visit <somewhere>` at the beginning of the first test so a page gets visited as `user`

One final note, you have a lot of duplication in your factories - you'd be better off writing it as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "test#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Test#{n}" }
    email { generate :email }
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"

    factory :friend do
      name 'Friend'
    end
  end
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice! I placed expect(page).to have_content "Some comments" after click_on "Add Comment" to ensure the comment by Friend is successfully submitted before logging out. However, i am now unable to logout Friend despite placing logout(:friend) after the expect statement. The tests passes if i logout and login manually (ie. clicking logout button and filling in sign in form)

Comment: I do have actioncable setup to allow live update of notifications to article author, but i doubt it is linked to this issue?

Comment: @diana If the `logout` is the one from `devise`/`warden` it takes the scope as the parameter (not the user), so in your case it should be `logout(:user)` - not :friend since you don't have a :friend scope, just a `friend` user instance

Comment: oh that sounds logical, but this still is not working for me... the screenshot captured still shows user on the articles page, with the cursor on the "Add Comment" button

Comment: I have checked the devise capybara test guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara, but still can't figure out what's wrong..

Comment: Hey, i managed to get all the tests passing by removing the expect(page).to have_content "Successfully logged out" and  expect(page).to have_content "Successfully logged in" statements. I will do some manual screenshots to verify all is well, thanks for your help!